# How to restrict apache-rat plugin from downloading jcenter dependencies

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, gradle, jcenter

Although I am downloading apache-rat gradle jar from a maven third-party repository, the url.host is being set to jcenter which leads to downloading all the dependencies from jcenter.

classpath 'gradle.plugin.org.nosphere.apache:creadur-rat-gradle:0.2.2'

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.